# Go webcrawler hangs after checking about 2000 urls

Tags: concurrency, go, freeze

I have a program to check whether keywords are on a web page. But after checking 1000-3000 urls, it hangs. There is no output, it does not exit, and the number of tcp connections is zero. I don't know why there are no new connections.

Would you give me some advice how to debug it?

```
type requestReturn struct {    
    url    string    
    status bool
}

var timeout = time.Duration(800 * time.Millisecond)    

func checkUrls(urls []string, kws string, threadLimit int) []string {    
    limitChan := make(chan int, threadLimit)    
    ok := make(chan requestReturn, 1)    
    var result []string    
    i := 0    
    for ; i < threadLimit; i++ {    
        go func(u string) {    
            request(u, limitChan, ok, kws)    
        }(urls[i])    
    }    
    for o := range ok {    
        if o.status {    
            result = append(result, o.url)    
            log.Printf("success %s,remain %d", o.url, len(urls)-i)    
        } else {    
            log.Printf("fail %s,remain %d", o.url, len(urls)-i)    
        }    
        if i < len(urls) {    
            go func(u string) {    
                request(u, limitChan, ok, kws)    
            }(urls[i])    
            i++    
        }    
    }    
    close(limitChan)    
    return result    
}    

func dialTimeout(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {    
    return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, timeout)    
}    

func request(url string, threadLimit chan int, ok chan requestReturn, kws string) {    
    threadLimit <- 1    
    log.Printf("%s, start...", url)    
    //startTime := time.Now().UnixNano()    
    rr := requestReturn{url: url}    

    transport := http.Transport{    
        Dial:              dialTimeout,    
        DisableKeepAlives: true,    
    }    

    client := http.Client{    
        Transport: &transport,    
        Timeout:   time.Duration(15 * time.Second),    
    }    

    resp, e := client.Get(url)    
    if e != nil {    
        log.Printf("%q", e)    
        rr.status = false    
        return    
    }    

    if resp.StatusCode == 200 {    
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)    
        if err != nil {    
            log.Printf("%q", err)    
            rr.status = false    
            return    
        }    

        content := bytes.NewBuffer(body).String()    

        matched, err1 := regexp.MatchString(kws, content)    
        if err1 != nil {    
            log.Printf("%q", err1)    
            rr.status = false    
        } else if matched {    
            rr.status = true    
            log.Println(rr.url)    
        } else {    
            rr.status = false    
        }    
    } else {    
        rr.status = false    
    }    

    defer (func() {    
        resp.Body.Close()    
        ok <- rr    
        //processed := float32(time.Now().UnixNano()-startTime) / 1e9    
        //log.Printf("%s, status:%t,time:%.3fs", rr.url, rr.status, processed)    
        <-threadLimit    
    })()    
}
```

Comment: Play post a formatted compilable code.

Comment: the complete code is :http://www.mediafire.com/view/p888clprdjkvlis/checkLinks.go

Comment: Is this on Windows by any chance? I have experience with Windows running out of network connections if you make more than about 3000 sockets in less than five minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using two forms of concurrency control in this code, and both have problems.

You've got `limitChan`, which looks like it is being used as a semaphore (`request` sends a value at its start, and receives a value in a `defer` in that function).  But `checkUrls` is also trying to make sure it only has `threadLimit` goroutines running at once (by spawning that number first up, and only spawning more when one reports its results on the `ok` channel).  Only one of these should be necessary to limit the concurrency.

Both methods fail due to the way the `defer` is set up in `request`.  There are a number of `return` statements that occur before `defer`, so it is possible for the function to complete without sending the result to the `ok` channel, and without freeing up its slot in `limitChan`.  After a sufficient number of errors, `checkUrls` will stop spawning new goroutines and you'll see your hang.

The fix is to place the `defer` statement before any of the `return` statements so you know it will always be run.  Something like this:

```
func request(url string, threadLimit chan int, ok chan requestReturn, kws string) {
    threadLimit <- 1
    rr := requestReturn{url: url}
    var resp *http.Response
    defer func() {
        if resp != nil {
            resp.Body.Close()
        }
        ok <- rr
        <-threadLimit
    }()
    ...
}
```